# Kafka - memory limit on the server

Tags: apache-kafka

I came to the memory limit on the server where kafka is installed.
Could you tell me how can I detect which topic takes the most space?
Or generally how to work on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard OS tools for finding which `log.dirs` directory is the largest. Kafka has no tool for this.

If "memory" you mean JVM heap size, then that's not related to topic size